# Vertically center rotated divs in viewport (window height)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two `fixed` divs, one on either side of the page.

I've rotated them 90 degrees and managed to get them to the sides.

However I can't get them to *vertically center*.

Also, I had to define `width` for the div to get the text to stay on one line, although I'd rather not have a set width because I don't have control of the text content..

```css
.nav-previous, .nav-next { 
  position:fixed;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
}

.nav-previous { left: 0px; }
.nav-next { right: 0px; }

.nav-previous a, .nav-next a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 1.25em; 
  color: #383838;
  margin: 0; padding: 20px;
}

.nav-previous a { 
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform:rotate(-90deg);      
}

.nav-next a { 
  left: 0; 
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform:rotate(90deg); 
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="nav-previous"><a href="#">previous</a></div>
  <div class="nav-next"><a href="#">next</a></div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/3hq6xgL4/

Comment: Why those crazy selectors (`[class*="navigation"]`)? What's wrong with `.navigation`?

Comment: I'm not sure. This will work for you or not? solution - 1:  https://jsfiddle.net/3hq6xgL4/2/  solution - 2:   https://jsfiddle.net/3hq6xgL4/3/

Comment: You can't set something vertically without knowing the height of it because it's all relative to the size of the element being set.

Comment: @waxi see my answer I have set it vertically without knowing the height, if you use the full page link in the snippet, you can resize your browser and you will see the text stays vertically centered

Comment: ? the snippet doesn't work but fiddle does (Firefox) not sure what you changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this - I have used `translate` to center the text:

```css
/* this vertically centres the containers */
.navigation .nav-previous, 
.navigation .nav-next { 
  display:inline-block;
  position:fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/*this moves the links onto the screen (after the translating and rotating is done*/
.navigation .nav-previous { left: 20px; }
.navigation .nav-next { right: 20px; }

.navigation .nav-previous a,
.navigation .nav-next a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 1.25em; 
  color: #383838;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 20px;
  transform-origin: center;      
}

.navigation .nav-previous a{
  transform: translate(-50%, 0) rotate(90deg); /* move left 50% before rotating*/
}
.navigation .nav-next a {
  transform: translate(50%, 0) rotate(90deg); /* move right 50% before rotating*/
}

/* styles below to show it is centered */
html,
body {height:100%; padding:0; margin:0;}
body:after {content:''; height:50%; background:blue; display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="nav-previous"><a href="3">previous</a></div>
  <div class="nav-next"><a href="#">next</a></div>
</div>
```